# How can I edit the Microsoft Word bibliography XML format in an intuitive way?

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-word, desktop-customization, citations

In Microsoft Word 2010 citation manager there is no possibility to edit the inline citation format or the bibliography format while the functionality **[is available through XML files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj851016.aspx)**.

Does Microsoft Word offer any functionality to edit these XML files through a GUI? If not, how else would I go about customizing the format without having to edit a raw XML file? I would prefer a solution in which users don't have to understand the XML format.

Comment: Check out [some](http://www.osalt.com/xmlspy) of these [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/altova-xmlspy/) to [Altova XMLspy](http://www.altova.com/xml-editor/) as found from [this SO Q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291593/is-there-a-gui-that-i-can-use-to-create-xml-documents-based-on-my-schema)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a tool for editing the XML files, there is BibWord: http://bibword.codeplex.com/

I have never found a way of editing the bibliographies in Word 2007 or Word 2010 through Word itself. I have not used Word 2013 to know.